# Method call as argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn both Ruby and Rails and I'm looking at Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial.org. In Chapter 7 or 8, he's working on sessions and I think he's using a method call as an argument to a function, but I'm not totally sure of it. It's not something I've seen before.

Please have a look at the first function in the "private" section below where the argument is `remember_token`.  does this mean that the return value of the function `remember_token` becomes the argument(s) for `User.authenticate_with_salt`?

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  private

    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
```

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but what makes this so weird-looking is not the splat operator but rather that nothing indicates that `remember_token` is a method. In most other languages, you need to do `remember_token()` or something to differentiate method from variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

It's also "splatted" (the `*`), meaning the return value (the cookie bits, or the `[nil, nil]` array if there's no cookie) is unpacked from the array, and sent as two individual parameters (roughly) to `User.authenticate_with_salt`.

Answer (score 0):

As @DaveNewton mentioned the ruby's "splat" operator is being used.

There's a lot you can do with splat so here's [a blog](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) with some great examples.

One thing to keep in mind is that splat can be used both while defining a method and also when calling a method.

```
# when defining a method
def my_method(name, age, *everything_else)
  ...
end

# when calling a method
some_info = other_method(*stuff)
```